# Using plot with title containing text, formulas and variables

Tags: r, graphics, plot

I want to make the title of my plot contain text, formulas and variables. Consider the toy example where I want the title to read as:

Histogram of normal distribution with (mu/sigma) equal to (value of mu/sigma)

(where the first bracket is to be rendered as a formula)

Based on some questions around this site, I tried the following code:

```
x <- rnorm(1000)
mu <- 1
sigma <- 0

hist(x, main=bquote("Histogram of normal distribution with " *frac(mu,sigma)* " equal to ", .(mu/sigma)  ) )
```

Now the problem is that the value of mu/sigma is not shown, like so:

[image: graph]

How can I get the last bit to show?

Comment: Wow, I thought I understood how bquote works.  I just can't get that value to show no matter what.  You might consider ggplot2, I remember there also being a way to get latex equations in plots. It might work for you.

Comment: `bquote` has only one `expr` argument, you should replace the comma by a `*`

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it:

```
title(main=substitute(paste("Histogram of normal distribution with ", 
                            frac(mu,sigma), " equal to ", frac(m,s)), 
                      list(m=mu, s=sigma)))
```